# Use of free() in PIC Microcontroller Programming

Tags: microcontroller, c, mplab

In my Microcontroller PIC18f4550 code, I am using a function which returns an array, I know, C doesn't allow to return an array so I am just returning the address using pointers. Now after the address is returned and performing some action on them, I am freeing the address value I stored in the pointer variable so that the function can be called again and new array address can be passed.

**My code(Just to explain):-**

```
int *a,ans[5];

while(1)
{
a=returnarray();
for(j=1;j<5;j++)
       {
          ans[j]=*(a+j);
       }
free(a);
}
```

**My problem:-**

I am using MPLABX with XC8 compiler and I am getting error shown on the free() statement, so is there a substitute for this function that I can use here or is there any other way I can perform this task.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if XC8 supports dynamic memory or not, but arrays are passed by reference so if you want to modify the array within the function you could pass one in as a parameter.

Comment: @PeterJ I am modifying the array after it is returned.I just thought I could keep my code simple and efficient. Worst case scenario, I will replace the function call with the content of the function :(

Comment: I'm quite sure that there's an error in the code, which is not related to XC8, but to C itself. Could you show how `returnarray()`  handles the array? Also, error messages are called _messages_, because they usually tell you what's wrong. Even if you don't understand it yet, could you post it? (If there are many, the first few lines are fine)

Comment: You can't free() something which you didn't first malloc() and you can't malloc() on an 8-bit PIC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

free() is always used in combination with malloc(). They both concern dynamic memory on the heap. If you look at section 5.5.7 of the [XC8 C Compiler User's Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002053E.pdf):

> Dynamic memory allocation, (heap-based allocation using `malloc`, etc.) is not supported on any 8-bit device. This is due to the limited amount of data memory, and that this memory is banked. The wasteful nature of dynamic memory allocation does not suit itself to the 8-bit PIC device architectures.

If you set the right, high, level of optimization (presuming you have the standard / pro version of the compiler), the compiler might see when the memory isn't needed anymore and rewrite it if necessary. This is only possible if your code is not too complicated.

With a low level of optimization, the compiler won't recognise this and the variable will behave as normally, its memory will be freed when the function in which it's a local variable returns (as with all variables on the stack). If this is in the main() function or we're talking about a global variable, that means never.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to `free()` memory that has been dynamically allocated (e.g. with `malloc`). None of that applies to XC8 as far as I'm aware.

In any case, with the code you posted, you didn't allocate any dynamic memory, so there is no need to free it.

Update your question to show the implementation of `returnarray` and I will amend my answer if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to implement a malloc-style allocation on the PIC or other small microcontroller, there are a few ways to go about it.  The simplest is to define:

```
#define POOL_SIZE 100 // Or however big it can be without running out of space

uint8_t mem_pool[POOL_SIZE];
#define pool_end (mem_pool+POOL_SIZE)
uint8_t *next_alloc;
void *malloc(uint8_t size)
{
  if (pool_end - next_alloc <= size)
  {
    uint8_t *ret = next_alloc;
    next_alloc += size;
    return ret;
  }
  else
    return 0;
}
void release(uint8_t *dat)
{
  next_alloc = dat;
}
```

Releasing any object would release that object *and everything that was released after it*.  In cases where this matches desired semantics, the above code would be much cheaper than supporting allocating and releasing memory in arbitrary sequence.  If one can divide allocations into two groups, and say that it's acceptable to have the release of an object also release all other objects *in the same group*, that simply requires making `pool_end` be a `uint8_t *` variable, and then adding:

```
void *umalloc(uint8_t size)
{
  if (pool_end - next_alloc <= size)
  {
    pool_end -= size;
    return pool_end;
  }
  else
    return 0;
}
void urelease(uint8_t *dat, uint8_t size)
{
  pool_end = dat+size;
}
```

Note that the `urelease` function, unlike `release`, needs to be told the size of the block that was allocated, but the total overhead for these approaches will be 2 bytes if using only `malloc/release` and 4 bytes if using `umalloc/urelease`, *with no additional per-block overhead*.

If one needs to allocate and release blocks in arbitrary sequence, it's possible for a PIC to support that, but doing so will add complexity and may result in memory fragmentation.  If e.g. one has a pool of 512 bytes and allocates 16 items whose sizes are alternately 27+1 bytes and 3+1 bytes (27 or 3 bytes of data, plus a one byte header) and one then releases all of the 27+1-byte items, one would have 448 bytes left, but have no space that could hold 28 bytes of data.  If one can work with the limitations of the double-ended pool shown above, such a design will have minimal overhead and require minimal code to use, but will allow memory to be divided among different purposes at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen free() function in micro-controller. I think that if you wrap your code in a function then the memory will be released as soon as the function will return (scope of variables comes into action).

Comment: Yeah but what about the variable in the calling function, I am calling the array return function for like 100 times and each time I should free the variable, I tried it without free() on C and it wasn't giving proper answers.

Comment: @Mohit - without seeing the function that's being called, this is just a guess, but chances are that there's some buffer already allocated, and the function just returns a pointer to that buffer. So each time you call the function you get the same address back, with whatever data was put there. Any problems you're having are in some other part of the code; calling `free()` won't fix them.